# How to say "rather"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder how to translate "rather" in the meanings labelled 2, 3, 4 in its [TheFreeDictionary entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rather):

> 1. More readily; preferably: *I'd rather go to the movies.*
> 2. More exactly; more accurately: *He's my friend, or rather he was my friend.*
> 3. To a certain extent; somewhat: *It's rather cold out. I was rather hoping you'd call.*
> 4. On the contrary: *This is not a thoughtful criticism. Rather it is an insult.*

For (1) I found *prefere* but the example sentences (2), (3) and (4) are not about preference. Do these, or at least some of them, have other translations usable in similar contexts?

Comment: Aren't 2 and 4 the same usage ("more precisely" / "more accurately")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, there isn't any one word that covers all those meanings.

> 1. More readily; preferably: *I'd rather go to the movies.*

*Prefere* can be used in this context, but I find it flows better to use *preferi* as a verb: ***Mi preferus iri al la kinejo***.

> 2. More exactly; more accurately: *He's my friend, or rather he was my friend.*

I agree with the others, that "*pli ĝuste*" is the most suitable expression for this context.

> 3. To a certain extent; somewhat: *It's rather cold out. I was rather hoping you'd call.*

"*Iom*" works here; another word used to mean "rather, quite" is "*sufiĉe*".

From [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#sufi%C4%89e):

> **3** Mezgrade, tolereble, konsiderinde: *li rimarkis en sufiĉe granda distanco du rajdantojnZ; sufiĉe gaja vivovesperoZ; cetere ĝi* (la muziko) *estis sufiĉe bonaZ; sufiĉe stranga estis tiu kostumoZ.*

ReVo advises against this usage, but it is quite common. Note that it is generally used in that sense to modify adjectives and adverbs, not verbs directly. Thus "*Mi sufiĉe esperis, ke vi vokos min*" sounds strange. For that I would use "*iom*", or, if the intent is to emphasize that you were indeed hoping for a call, I'd say "*ja*".

> 4. On the contrary: *This is not a thoughtful criticism. Rather it is an insult.*

One could use "*pli ĝuste*" here, but "*kontraŭe*" or "*male*" are more suitable.

Answer (score 8):

[John Well’s dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) suggests *iom* and *pli ĝuste* as translations for *rather*. I think *iom* is a suitable translation for 3, and *pli ĝuste* is suitable for 2 and 4. So you could maybe translate your sentences as follows:

> Li estas mia amiko, aŭ **pli ĝuste** li estis mia amiko. (2)
>
> Estas **iom** malvarme ekstere. Mi **iom** esperis ke vi vokus. (3)
>
> Tio ne estas ĝentila kritiko. **Pli ĝuste** ĝi estas insulto. (4)

Here are some examples of *pli ĝuste* from Tekstaro to confirm this meaning:

> Kaj mi diras al vi, ke tiel estas… junaj, bonmanieraj, belfiguraj komizoj faras bonan efekton, altiras al la magazeno la aĉetantojn, aŭ **pli ĝuste** la aĉetantinojn…
>
> Sed en la mezo sur la ŝranko staris skulptita tuta viro; li havis ridindan aspekton, kaj li mem efektive ridis, aŭ **pli ĝuste** li rikanis, ĉar oni neniel povis tion nomi ridado.

Answer (score 7):

For meaning (2), Neil's answer is best

> Li estas mia amiko, aŭ **pli ĝuste** li estis mia amiko. (2)

I think meaning (3) should be divided into two submeanings [from Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rarther&oq=rarther&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.809j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=rather), (3a) and (3b)

> to a certain or significant extent or degree. (3a)
>
> used before verbs as a way of making the expression of a feeling or opinion less assertive. (3b)

For (3a), **relative** is good. The meaning (3b) can also be achieved with an uncertainty word, like **eble**, **verŝajne** or **certe**.

> Estas **relative** malvarme ekstere. (3a)
>
> Mi **eble** esperis, ke vi vokus min. (3b)

For (4) the contrast between the two statements is made big if a word like **malgraŭe**, **kontraŭe** or **anstantaŭe** is used

> Ĉi tio ne estas konsiderita kritiko. **Kontraŭe**, ĝi estas insulto. (4)

Comment: "Mi eble esperis, ke vi vokus min" to me means "Maybe I thought you would call me" which isn't quite the meaning conveyed by "rather".

Answer (score 4):

> I'd rather go to the movies.

Mi preferus iri al la kinejo.

> He's my friend, or rather he was my friend.

Li estas mia amiko, aŭ pli ĝuste li estis mia amiko.

> It's rather cold out.

Estas sufiĉe malvarme ekstere.

> I was rather hoping you'd call.

Pli ĝuste, mi esperas, ke vi telefonus min.

> Rather it is an insult.

Pli ĝuste estas insulto.

Answer (score 2):

Estas senfine da eblecoj, kiel montris la aliaj respondoj. Jen kiel mi esprimus la frazojn.

1. More readily; preferably: I'd rather go to the movies.

   **Mi preferus** iri kinejen. (*prefere, pli volonte, pli bone ...*)
2. More exactly; more accurately: He's my friend, or rather he was my friend.

   Aŭ **pli ĝuste**, li estis mia amiko. (*fakte, pli precize ...*)
3. To a certain extent; somewhat: It's rather cold out. I was rather hoping you'd call.

   Estas **sufiĉe** malvarme. Mi **iomete/parte** esperis, ke vi alvokos. (*certagrade, relative, konsiderinde ...*)
4. On the contrary: This is not a thoughtful criticism. Rather it is an insult.

   **Male**, estas insulto. (*kontraŭe*)